# Can an Xbox 360 and an Xbox One play online together with Disney Infinity 2.0?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, disney-infinity-2.0

I am new to the Xbox ecosystem, and my sons best friend has an Xbox 360 with Disney Infinity Marvel ( 2.0 ).

I want to get my son an Xbox so he can play online with his friend on Xbox Live.

**Do I need to get an Xbox 360 or can an Xbox One play with an Xbox 360 on the same title on Xbox Live?**

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think any game is compatible across the two generations of Xbox. So I would get an Xbox 360 as I know that they will be able to play together across xbox live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% positive that XBox 360 and Xbox 1 aren't compatible.  Some games you can upload prior accomplishments to the XB1, but actually playing together on different systems isn't possible.  Microsoft has also stated that wanted to make that possible but with the technology being so different in the two systems, that it was impossible (nearly).  Hope this helps.